# Latex table is not formatting properly

Tags: tables

I need tiny help! My latex table is not getting formatting Properly! Anyone can help me How I can fix the issue?

Latex Code is

```tex
\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{Hardness comparison}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|} 
\hline
\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}\textbf{BFO} \\\textbf{K\_\$\{IC\}\$(MPa.m\textsuperscript{0.5})} \\\textbf{Niihara´s eq.} \\\textbf{~}\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}\textbf{BLFO} \\\textbf{\textbf{K\_\$\{IC\}\$}(MPa.m\textsuperscript{0.5})} \\\textbf{Niihara´s eq.}\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}\textbf{BFNbO} \\\textbf{\textbf{K\_\$\{IC\}\$}(MPa.m\textsuperscript{0.5})} \\\textbf{Niihara´s eq.}\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}\textbf{BFO} \\\textbf{\textbf{K\_\$\{IC\}\$}~(MPa.m\textsuperscript{0.5})} \\\textbf{Anistis´s eq.}\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}\textbf{BLFO} \\\textbf{\textbf{K\_\$\{IC\}\$}~(MPa.m\textsuperscript{0.5})} \\\textbf{Anistis´s eq.}\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}\textbf{BFNbO} \\\textbf{\textbf{K\_\$\{IC\}\$}~(MPa.m\textsuperscript{0.5})} \\\textbf{Anistis´s eq.}\end{tabular}  \\ 
\hline
0.19                                                                                                                                            & 0.10                                                                                                                                         & 0.04                                                                                                                                          & 0.18                                                                                                                                         & 0.08                                                                                                                                          & 0.04                                                                                                                                            \\ 
\hline
0.25                                                                                                                                            & 0.09                                                                                                                                         & 0.22                                                                                                                                          & 0.17                                                                                                                                         & 0.07                                                                                                                                          & 0.16                                                                                                                                            \\ 
\hline
0.19                                                                                                                                            & 0.37                                                                                                                                         & 0.09                                                                                                                                          & 0.17                                                                                                                                         & 0.24                                                                                                                                          & 0.08                                                                                                                                            \\ 
\hline
0.27                                                                                                                                            & 0.28                                                                                                                                         & 0.29                                                                                                                                          & 0.27                                                                                                                                         & 0.28                                                                                                                                          & 0.28                                                                                                                                            \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

[image: Table issue]

Comment: Please make your code compilable by adding the documentclass as well as the relevant packages (See also: [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)) Since the most obvious issue with your table is the fact that it exceeds the available text width, you may be interested in taking a look at: [My table doesn't fit; what are my options?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/332902/134144)

Comment: In order to save some space in your table, you may want to consider removing the repeated `\textbf{K\_\$\{IC\}\$(MPa.m\textsuperscript{0.5})}`. You could probably explain it in the caption of your table, instead. Likewise, I'd suggest using shared column headers in order to avoid repeating the names of the equations.

Comment: Is the reason for all those `\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}` solely so that you can have a few newlines?

Comment: Problem Has been the Same! Yet not get solved after replacing the code!

Comment: Off topic: `K\_\$\{IC\}\$` looks weird.  Are you sure you don't want `K\textsubscript{IC}`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You really need to simplify the header cells, as they contain lots of redundancies that make them unreadable and the table much too wide.

I suggest something like the following.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,booktabs,siunitx}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{Hardness comparison\tnote{*}}
\begin{tabular}{@{} cccccc @{}} 
\toprule
\multicolumn{3}{@{}c}{Niihara's eq.} & 
\multicolumn{3}{c@{}}{Anistis's eq.} \\
\cmidrule(r){1-3} \cmidrule(l){4-6}
BFO & BLFO & BFNbO & BFO & BLFO & BFNbO \\
\midrule
0.19 & 0.10 & 0.04 & 0.18 & 0.08 & 0.04 \\ 
0.25 & 0.09 & 0.22 & 0.17 & 0.07 & 0.16 \\ 
0.19 & 0.37 & 0.09 & 0.17 & 0.24 & 0.08 \\ 
0.27 & 0.28 & 0.29 & 0.27 & 0.28 & 0.28 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\footnotesize
\begin{tablenotes}
\item[*] K\_\$\{IC\}\$(MPa.m\textsuperscript{0.5}), or 
   maybe K\textsubscript{IC} (\unit{\mega\pascal\meter\tothe {0.5}})
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}

\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Table, as you have now, if far to wide that can be fit  on page. Also in firsr row you in each cell repeat data `\textbf{K\_\$\{IC\}\$(MPa.m\textsuperscript{0.5})`. You may consider to move this for example in caption of table, for example as >I done in MWE below (well, context and meaning of table headers is unknown to me, so you probably should rephrase caption text).

By use of the `tabularray` package with `siunitx` library (which load `siunitx` package), you can write your document example as follows:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{siunitx}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
    \begin{table}[ht]
\caption{Comparison of the K\_IC hardness measured in  (\unit{\mega\pascal\sqrt{m}})}
\begin{tblr}{hlines, vlines,
             colspec = {*{6}{X[c, si ={table-format=1.2}]}},
              colsep = 4pt,
              row{1} = {font=\small\bfseries}
             } 
{{{BFO\\ Niihara´s eq.}}}
        &   {{{BLFO\\ Niihara´s eq.}}}
                &   {{{BFNbO\\ Niihara´s eq.}}}
                        &   {{{BFO\\ Anistis´s eq.}}}
                                &   {{{BLFO\\ Anistis´s eq.}}}
                                        &   {{{BFNbO\\ Anistis´s eq.}}}   \\
0.19    & 0.10  & 0.04  & 0.18  & 0.08  & 0.04      \\
0.25    & 0.09  & 0.22  & 0.17  & 0.07  & 0.16      \\
0.19    & 0.37  & 0.09  & 0.17  & 0.24  & 0.08      \\
0.27    & 0.28  & 0.29  & 0.27  & 0.28  & 0.28      \\
\end{tblr}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If suggested solution is not acceptable to you, the only reasonable option is rotate table into `landscape` orientation.